# Routing controller with optional Id not in parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm currently struggling in a problem where I need to register a route like:

```
https://localhost:44300/oneController/{Guid}/method1?param1=10000&param2=stuff
```

What I've tried was something similar to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> method1(Guid id, int param1, string param2)
{
    ...
}
```

However, this does not seems to work, any ideas to resolve this issue?

Comment: may be you need to switch ``{Guid}`` with ``method1``

Comment: Also, should change `{Guid}` to `{id}`.

Comment: @Sajid, actually op wants to call `method1` with the given route and due to different structure of route instead of 1\`controller\actionmethod?querystringparameters`, he want id to be part of URL. changing `{guid}` to `method1` while not help here. correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RouteAttribute`, like

```
[Route("{id:guid}/method1"), HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> method1(Guid id, int param1, string param2)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Good to read MSDN Documentation: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)